# Virtualbox failed to import VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-7

I tried to import my `Centos 7` VM into another Virtyualbox and i got this result

```
Medium 'E:\VirtualBox\OSSEC server Centos 7_\centos7-disk001_1.vmdk' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines.


Result Code: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80BB000C)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

i search on forums but none of them works for my vm...
my virtual box version is  `5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2)`

Comment: Are there any other VM in VIrtualbox?

Comment: @Biswa Yes there are two, kali vm and devian vm